# What parts of the Central or South Coast of California should I consider when looking for a surfing beach with beachfront hotels?

Tags: hotels, beaches, recommendations, southern-california, surfing

After asking "[What affordable beachfront hotels in or near San Diego should I consider?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/what-affordable-beachfront-hotels-in-or-near-san-diego-should-i-consider/2710)", it occurred to me I may want to consider other areas of the [South Coast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Coast_%28California%29) or even [Central Coast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Coast_of_California) of California.  Where else (other than San Diego) would I find affordable beachfront hotels, with easy access to surfing for beginners?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

South Coast cities famous for surfing and great beaches:

- Malibu - you must check out the regional classic point break at the Malibu Lagoon. Contests are held throughout the year and surfers are crowding for the best waves at other times. Finding affordable accommodation is tricky, but the [Calabasas Good Nite Inn](http://www.goodnite.com/calabasas/) seems about the best cost vs distance option.
- Santa Monica - more touristy than Malibu and with the famous pier, the promenade stretches a couple of miles to Venice Beach.  Cheapest I can find is the Pacific Sands Motel, 1515 Ocean Ave., ☎ (310) 395-6133 with rooms from $55,
- Pacific Beach - numbers surge in summer, especially at the Tourmaline Surfing Park.  [The Banana Bungalow](http://www.bananabungalowsandiego.com/index.html) is a chain of hostels here, and is probably your cheapest option.
- Santa Barbara - There's actually a hostel here (Santa Barbara Tourist Hostel), with [beds from US$30](http://www.hostelbookers.com/property/index.cfm?fuseaction=propertydynamic.overview&intpropertyid=1831).
- Newport beach

  and more.

to check these out, have a look at the [various webcams for these beaches](http://socalforecast.blogspot.com/).

Highlights on the Central Coast:

Big Sur - a small town where tourists can get away from it all (albeit with other tourists) - perched on a cliff over the ocean.   To be fair, the surfing here would be a bit rubbish but it's a highlight on the way down the coast.

Monterey (in Monterey Bay) - with five public beaches, there's tons to do here.  As much as I dislike promoting HI Hostels, there's one here called Hostelling International Monterey which seems like the best budget accommodation.

Santa Barbara - There are numerous beaches in the area fit for surfing and several companies that rent surfboards. Although the surf tends to be much smaller in the summer, it is perfect for beginners. There are also several nice long board breaks that are suitable year round. Impressively there's a [hostel 2 blocks from the beach](http://www.sbhostel.com) as well!

Santa Cruz - a variety of beaches, some of which are a surfer's paradise.  The Surf Museum is here too.  Easy waves for novices in summer, big breaks in winter especially in front of the lighthouse.  Worth noting that it's illegal to sleep in your car here, so you'll need a hotel - best I can find is the [Adobe on Green Street Bed and Breakfast](http://www.adobeongreen.com/) - the Dream Inn is too touristy and some view it as overpriced.

Of course there are lots of beaches all along the coast, and as you drive down you may spot a beach that looks amazing.  If you find a gem, feel free to add it to this page!

Comment: There's also [a hostel in Santa Monica](http://www.hilosangeles.org/). It's one of those big impersonal ones where they buzz you in and out. Prices seem to start at about $39 USD for a shared dormitory, including tax.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111048/how-can-i-assign-a-bounty-that-expired-before-i-noticed-an-answer-that-didnt-ap

Comment: @DarylSpitzer - not sure that you can, unfortunately. They even give a grace period in case you've just missed it by a few hours, but sadly, I've wasted a few myself by accident.  No worries though, an accept is all I need :)